# Matching between GeoServer and PostGIS entities

Tags: postgis, geoserver, sql

I need to use PostGIS to store GeoServer data, however, I do not quite understand the matching between Geoserver entities and SQL entities.
In particular, I am interested in knowing what the workspace, store, and layer correspond to in PostGIS.

Comment: Please clarify what parts remain unclear after reading  https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/database/postgis.html.

Comment: I had already read something on this page before I asked the question, but unfortunately I find several things ambiguous. For example, it is not clear whether a workspace can contain only one database or more than one, nor is it explained how a layer is stored in the database, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A store is the way GeoServer refers to a source of data (e.g. a Database schema, shapefile, etc), a layer is a set of features (e.g. a table, view or file).

A workspace is a way of storing data sets together like a folder on your desktop.